# Stunnel and FIX

Tags: stunnel

I am trying to use Stunnel to connect to a remote server through a proxy (I am using stunnel 4.56).

Here is my config file `stunnel.conf`:

```
cert = stunnel.pem
key = stunnel.pem

[https]
accept = 127.0.0.1:556
protocolHost= 128.45.65.36:80
connect = 556.79.65.20:80
verify = 0
```

Each time I double-click on `stunnel.exe`, all I get in the logs is :

```
2013.04.25 17:17:00 LOG5[3272:8956]: Reading configuration from file stunnel.conf
2013.04.25 17:17:00 LOG5[3272:8956]: FIPS mode is enabled
2013.04.25 17:17:00 LOG5[3272:8956]: Configuration successful
```

Someone knows what is the problem? I expect at least an error saying that he cannot connect but nothing here ...

Comment: Stunnel is not a VPN, it is basically a proxy.  It does not open a persistent connection when the daemon is launched.  It will not make a connection to the remote host until you connect to the listening port.

Answer (score 4):

I finally managed to make it work. I now have the following `stunnel.conf` file:

```
; Certificate
cert = stunnel.pem
;FIPS
fips=no
; Protocol version (all, SSLv2, SSLv3, TLSv1)
sslVersion = all

; Some performance tunings  
socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1  
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1  

; Some debugging stuff useful for troubleshooting  
debug = 7  
output = stunnel.log  

; Use it for client mode  
client = yes

; Service-level configuration
[FIX]  
accept = 127.0.0.1:port
connect = proxy:80
protocol=connect
protocolHost= target-server:443
TIMEOUTconnect  = 5
```

Basically I want to connect to a FIX server through a proxy. The connection is now made but it seems their server is not accepting my connection. I see this in the stunnel logs :

```
2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]: SSL state (connect): before/connect initialization
2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]: SSL state (connect): SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 read server hello A
2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 read server certificate A
2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 read server done A
2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 write client key exchange A
2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 write finished A
2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 flush data
2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 read finished A
2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]:    1 items in the session cache
2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]:    1 client connects (SSL_connect())

2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]:    1 client connects that finished

2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]:    0 client renegotiations requested

2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]:    0 server connects (SSL_accept())

2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]:    0 server connects that finished
2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]:    0 server renegotiations requested
2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]:    0 session cache hits
2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]:    0 external session cache hits
2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]:    0 session cache misses
2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]:    0 session cache timeouts
```

I think I might need to input a login and password. Someone knows how to do this with stunnel? I tried `protocolCredentials` but it does not work.

Comment: This line means that the target server is not accepting my connection ? "2013.04.26 14:05:06 LOG7[12312:13560]: 0 server connects (SSL_accept())"

Comment: This line means that the target server is not accepting my connection ?